# Image Submission on form (MERN stack)

Tags: mongodb, express, backend, mern, image-upload

I am making a car dealership/listing website. I want users to go to a form, add details about their car and add images. I have tried multiple solutions and still have trouble figuring out how I can have the images along side the other information in a listing.

I have tried using multer with an uploads folder and saving it to mongoDB, but with no avail. I also considered options like firebase or cloudinary but I could not get a concrete solution to my problem.

Comment: “I have tried using multer with an uploads folder and saving it to mongoDB, but with no avail”—starting with this question and code would be a better fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.